# How to keep bottom sheet in backstack when navigating forward?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am using Accompanist [Bottom Sheet Destinations](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-material/#bottom-sheet-destinations) in my project. The setup is exactly the same as shown in docs.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val bottomSheetNavigator = rememberBottomSheetNavigator()
    val navController = rememberNavController(bottomSheetNavigator)
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(bottomSheetNavigator) {
        NavHost(navController, Destinations.Home) {
           composable(route = "home") {
               HomeScreen(
                   openBottomSheet = { navController.navigate("sheet")  }
               )
           }
           bottomSheet(route = "sheet") {
               MyBottonSheet(
                   navigateToSomeRoute = { navController.navigate("some_route") }
               )
           }
           composable(route = "some_route") {
               SomeComposable(
                   onBackPress = { navController.navigateUp() }
               )
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have a button in `MyBottomSheet` which opens the `SomeComposable` screen. But when I navigateUp from there, I reach `HomeScreen` i.e. the bottom sheet was popped off the backstack when I navigated away from it. How can I keep my bottom sheet in the backstack so that when I press Back in `SomeComposable` I go back to the previous state with `MyBottonSheet` open (on top of `HomeScreen`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. As per the [Navigation and the back stack documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack):

> Dialog destinations implement the [`FloatingWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/FloatingWindow) interface, indicating that they overlay other destinations on the back stack. As such, one or more `FloatingWindow` destinations can be present only on the top of the navigation back stack. **Navigating to a destination that does not implement `FloatingWindow` automatically pops all `FloatingWindow` destinations off of the top of the stack.** This ensures that the current destination is always fully visible above other destinations on the back stack.

Bottom sheet destinations are also `FloatingWindow` destinations that float above the other destinations. As such, it is expected that they are automatically popped off the back stack when you navigate to anything other than another `dialog` or `bottomSheet` destination.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If this is the case then I think I will have to navigate to the bottom sheet again when I reach Home.

Comment: Or you shouldn't be using a bottom sheet for something that needs to go on the back stack - bottom sheets and other dialog destinations should be for temporary overlays (which is exactly what they look like from the user's perspective).

Comment: Google maps does it. It opens a bottom sheet when you click on a marker, and if you click on anything in the bottom sheet and go back, the bottom sheet is still open.